# Nan results when concatenating dataframes of different indices

Tags: pandas

I have 3 dataframes I would like to concatenate  maintaining the index of df1.

```
df1:                      
       sq/ft               

R     0.026715            
A    -0.016556            
P     0.007440      
V     0.009841 


 df2:  
       ml/sq

0     0.032394
1     0.065046
2     0.009021
3     0.041041

df3:
       mlsq/rt
0     0.000871
1    -0.000148
2     0.000484
3     0.026715
```

The desired output would be something like this:

```
       sq/ft         ml/sq     mlsq/rt           

R     0.026715     0.032394   0.000871       
A    -0.016556     0.065046  -0.000148
P     0.007440     0.009021   0.000484
V     0.009841     0.041041   0.026715
```

This is what I have tried following pandas doc:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#set-logic-on-the-other-axes

```
print(pd.concat([df2,df1,df3], axis=1, join_axes=[df1.index]))
```

The 3 of them are df and my current output is

```
      ml/sq         sq/ft

R      NaN       0.026715
A      NaN      -0.016556
P      NaN       0.007440
V      NaN       0.009841
```

df3 it isn't even returned as an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need align indexes - simpliest is set indexes in `df2.index` and `df3.index` by `df1.index`:

```
df2.index = df1.index
df3.index = df1.index
print(pd.concat([df2,df1,df3], axis=1))
```